# GSevent/UITouch penetrate top layer UIWindow to act on another UIWindow (iOS, theos, jailbreak)

Tags: ios, objective-c, theos

A and B are 2 UIWindow and B has higher UIWindowLevel.

Now I want B to be "transparent" to UITouch event--

When I touch a point inside UIWindow B, UIWindow A will receive the touch event.

How do I do that? Is it possible to achieve that by hooking to some ios classes?

```
+-------------------+
|     A             |
|  +--------+       |
|  |  B     |       |
|  |        |       |
|  +--------+       |
|                   |
+-------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following override in the 'transparent' `UIView`:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return NO;
}
```

An alternative is the following override:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    return self.superview;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide more details of how to implement the override method?  Windows B is created via the following code:

`%hook SpringBoard
%new(v@:)
- (void)floatWinOn{
//...
floatWindow= [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    floatWindow.windowLevel = winlevel;
    [floatWindow setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
    [floatWindow setHidden:NO];}`

Comment: Override in `B`. Both `A` and `B` should be subclassing `UIView`.

Comment: yeah, you are right. However, it seems to be difficult to implement.  Existing examples works on UIView and the subclassing is like this:    _@interface UnderneathButtonView : UIView {    _@private    UIButton *underneathButton;    }  What should I use to replace "UnderneathButtonView" when I replace "UIButton *underneathButton" with "UIWindow *windowB"?